# Convert Datatable to strogly Typed Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a model class like this

```
public class Profile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    ...................... etc

}
```

And a datatable which is of same type of data. Means columns in datattable will be `FirstName,LastName,NickName,City,State`. And the data table will have only one row.
Now I want to copy the data in  this datatable to `Profile` model. Right now I am doing like this.

```
   var sp = new Profile();
    DataTable dt = ProfileDAL.GetProfile(profileId);
    if (profile.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        sp.FirstName = ReferenceEquals(dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"], "")
            ? ""
            : dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
        sp.LastName = ReferenceEquals(dt.Rows[0]["LastName"], "")
            ? ""
            : dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        sp.NickName = ReferenceEquals(dt.Rows[0]["NickName"], "")
            ? ""
            : dt.Rows[0]["NickName"].ToString();
   }
```

is there any elegant way of doing this? Like I have a huge datatable to convert and when I do it like what I am doing now. It will take a long time and a number of lines of code. Can anyone point out anything better?

Comment: where is `foreach` loop?

Comment: @SidM It was a mistake in my question corrected now

Comment: did u check my answer ?

Comment: best way is AutoMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I used that saved me time. I created it as an extension to DataTable. All you have to do is

```
DataTable dt = ProfileDAL.GetProfile(profileId);
var profile = dt.Rows[0].ToEntity<Profile>();  //<-- new changes
```

And if you want a list

```
DataTable dt = ProfileDAL.GetProfiles();
var profiles = dt.ToList<Profile>();
```

Or get your entity with LINQ

```
DataTable dt = ProfileDAL.GetProfile(profileId);
var profile = dt.ToList<Profile>().FirstOrDefault();
```

**The class**

```
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static T ToEntity<T>(this DataRow dr) where T : new()
    {
      DataColumnCollection columns = dr.Table.Columns;
      T obj1 = new T();
      foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        if (columns.Contains(propertyInfo.Name) && dr[propertyInfo.Name] != DBNull.Value)
        {
          if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
          {
            object obj2 = Convert.ChangeType(dr[propertyInfo.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            propertyInfo.SetValue((object) obj1, obj2, (object[]) null);
          }
          else
          {
            object obj2 = Convert.ChangeType(dr[propertyInfo.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            propertyInfo.SetValue((object) obj1, obj2, (object[]) null);
          }
        }
      }
      return obj1;
    }

    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : new()
    {
      List<T> list = new List<T>();
      foreach (DataRow dr in (InternalDataCollectionBase) dt.Rows)
        list.Add(DataExtensions.ToEntity<T>(dr));
      return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help. This is what exactly I was looking for. But I got some issues in using this extension probably my little knowledge on the cases like this. I am getting an error like this

Comment: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'ToEntity' and the best extension method overload 'BL.DataExtensions.ToEntity<T>(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Sorry my bad! I have updated the answer. The code for entity is slightly different. Instead of `var profile = dt.ToEntity<Profile>();` it should be `var profile = dt.Rows[0].ToEntity<Profile>();` because the to `.ToEntity` takes `DataRow` and not `DataTable`.

Comment: Yes it works now. And I want you to know that the extension is supercool. You Rocks

Comment: You are welcome. It took me time to get there after several attempt to make db access easier. You improve as you develop and refactor you code. Also checkout Dapper and other mini ORMs

Answer (score 1):

here is solution i use this for map data table with entity

or you can use the **AutoMapper**

```
IList<Profile> result = new List<Profile>();


result = currentDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Profile
             {
                 FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
                 LastName = row["LastName"].ToString()
             }
             ).ToList<Profile>();
```